# send cmdlet pipe output to out-null by default?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to automatically send the pipe output of a cmdlet to out-null unless it's explicitly assigned to a variable or piped to out-host?

For example, let's say I have a script with many cmdlets that dump a don't care object to the console that you don't want to save or look at:

```
mkdir dir1 | out-null
mkdir dir2 | out-null
mkdir dir3 | out-null
```

The only way I've found to get around this is to pipe the output to out-null or assign it to a variable that I throw away.  What I want to do, is at the top of my script reassign the out-default to out-null to have the effect above.  I just think its tiresome to always need to put "out-null" on everyline in order to avoid having powershell: "automatically send the pipe output of a cmdlet to out-null unless it's explicitly assigned to a variable or piped to out-host"

Is it Possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize default parameters.  This will be used every time you call `New-Item` (which `mkdir` aliases to)

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
    'New-Item:OutVariable' = 'Null'
    'Disabled' = $False
}
```

---

After testing, the above method *shouldn't* work, so your alternative is creating a function at the start of the script:

```
Function New-Dir
{
    Param([Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)][String]$Path)

    #force creates subfolders if they don't exist
    New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType Directory -Force >$Null 
}
```

Comment: @BillMoore It's an automatic variable [that is well-documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-5.1).  You can utilize the `Disabled` member to turn it off after you're done.  You can also limit its scope based on how you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that its possible, except its still a little bit broken.  Example:

```
   PS> function out-default {$input | out-null}

   #ok. Works great
   PS> mkdir xyz
   # output directory object is sent to null and not displayed to out-host

   #now explictly asking for the object to override out-default
   PS> mkdir xyz123 | out-host
   Directory: C:\Users\john\sandbox\tmp
   Mode      LastWriteTime    Length   Name
   ---       -------------    ------   ----
   ---       12/19/2017       1:26 PM  xyz123
```

The problem is that it works TOO well, because let's say you want to save the object to a return varable.

```
   PS> $dir = mkdir xyz2

   PS> $dir
   #nothing to returned!
```

On the positive side, the override of out-default is easy to delete:

```
   PS> del function:out-default
```

Now the expected default behavior is reverted:

```
   PS> $dir = mkdir xyz3

   PS> $dir
   Directory: C:\Users\john\sandbox\tmp2
    Mode      LastWriteTime    Length   Name
    ---       -------------    ------   ----
    ---       12/19/2017       1:26 PM  xyz3

   PS> mkdir xyz4
   Directory: C:\Users\john\sandbox\tmp2
   Mode      LastWriteTime    Length   Name
   ---       -------------    ------   ----
   ---       12/19/2017       1:26 PM  xyz4
```

Would be nice if assigning a variable was separate from out-default.  Because then you could just leave the out-default assigned to out-null for the entire script without worrying about breaking the script.

Comment: Clever, although arguably evil-er than my single-use suggestion since it affects ALL output.  [Today, I learned.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-default?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Just as a suggestion, I'd avoid using aliases in your scripts, especially if they're shared among team-members.  It's always a good practice to make your code as readable as possible.  Aliases are great for CLI tooling around, but not great when someone's trying to figure out what `SLS` is

Comment: As it stands, I agree... however, Its almost not evil...  I kind of feel like it might be possible to assign the variable with the pipe output while still redirecting console output to null... maybe a new out-null cmdlet with this behavior?  no idea how to implement it however...

Comment: As it stands, the easiest way is to wrap the command in your own function or overload the function name: `Function New-Item { Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\New-Item @PSBoundParameters >$Null }`.  Also, `Out-Null` is way slower than the other 3 methods (assigning to variable, file redirect to null, or void casting)